# Statistics and Probability (standard deviation)

Tags: probability

Im finding this to be quite tricky, any ideas?

A doctor is responsible for making treatment decisions for a group of patients who are suﬀering from a slow-acting non-fatal disease, x. The disease remains dormant (with no symptoms) for a time which is approximately normally distributed with mean 20 years and standard deviation 8 years. The remaining lifetime of the patients is approximately normally distributed with mean 30 years and standard deviation 12 years.

What is the probability that a randomly chosen patient will suﬀer from the symptoms of disease x within his/her lifetime

Comment: So, for clarification, if symptoms show after $D$ years and the patient lives a total of $L$ years, what is the probability that $D<L$?

Comment: Correct, i don't quite know how to go this. Any ideas?

Comment: Try looking into the random variable $Z=L-D = L+(-D)$ and the probability that it is greater than $0$. What is the distribution of $Z$?

Answer (score 1):

A linear combination of normally distributed random variables is itself a normally distributed random variable.

In particular, if $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed random variables with means $\mu_X, \mu_Y$ and variances $\sigma_X^2,\sigma_Y^2$, then $Z=X+Y$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu_X+\mu_Y$ and variance $\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2$. So, in this case, you have time until symptoms show is $D$ with $\mu_D=20$ and $\sigma_D^2=8^2=64$, and the remaining lifespan is $L$ with $\mu_L=30$ and $\sigma_L^2=12^2=144$.

What you want to find is $P(D<L)$, which is equal to $P(D-L<0)$. According to the above, $D-L$ is normally distributed with mean $20-30=-10$ and variance $64+144=208$ (because negating $L$ does not change the variance), which means the standard deviation is $\sqrt{208}\approx14.42$.
Therefore, you are looking for the probability that a normally distributed random variable is more than $10/14.42\approx0.693$ standard deviations above the mean, which you can easily find with a normal distribution table.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Let $D$ denote the number of years after which the symptoms appear, and $L$ the number of years that the patient lives. These are independent random variables, distributed according to given normal distributions. 
$$
\text{P}\left( D \le L \right)
=
\text{P}\left( D - L \le 0 \right).
$$
Let $Z = D-L = D+(-L)$.

- What is the distribution of the random variable $Z$?
- Taking a step back, what is the distribution of the random variable $-L$ (multiplying a normally distributed random variable with a constant)?
- What is the distribution of the sum of two independent normally distributed random variables?